# scheme/racket solving simultaneous equations

Tags: scheme, racket, dxf

Given 2 points and a signed bulge factor (whether the arc connects from the first point to the second point in a CW or CCW manner), calculate the center point of the arc.

```
(define (solver x1 y1 x2 y2 bulge)
  (let* ((arc-angle (* 4 (atan bulge)))
         (chord-length (/ (sqrt (+ (expt (abs (- x1 x2)) 2) (expt (abs (- y1 y2)) 2))) 2))
         (radius (/ chord-length (cos (/ (- pi arc-angle) 2)))))
    (list arc-angle chord-length radius)))

> (solver 3 10 10 5 0.592)
'(2.1380655244738884 4.301162633521313 4.905882850266661)

with the equations (x-3)^2 + (y-10)^2 = 4.05^2
                   (x-10)^2 + (y-5)^2 = 4.05^2
solve to find x, y.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the solution formula for this system of equations:

```
(x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 = r^2
(x-x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2 = r^2
```

where (x,y) are the center of the circle,
and (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are points on the circle.

Giving these equations to Wolfram Alpha gives these solutions:

```
x = (-sqrt(-(y1-y2)^2 (x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2) (-4 r^2+x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2))+x1^3-x1^2 x2-x1 x2^2+x1 y1^2-2 x1 y1 y2+x1 y2^2+x2^3+x2 y1^2-2 x2 y1 y2+x2 y2^2)/(2 (x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2))
```

and

```
y = (x1 sqrt(-(y1-y2)^2 (x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2) (-4 r^2+x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2))-x2 sqrt(-(y1-y2)^2 (x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2) (-4 r^2+x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2))+x1^2 y1^2-x1^2 y2^2-2 x1 x2 y1^2+2 x1 x2 y2^2+x2^2 y1^2-x2^2 y2^2+y1^4-2 y1^3 y2+2 y1 y2^3-y2^4)/(2 (y1-y2) (x1^2-2 x1 x2+x2^2+y1^2-2 y1 y2+y2^2))
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get what you meant at first.. but is there a way to implement a generic solver for systems of equations in racket?

Comment: Well, a generic solver is a lot of work. Even a general solver for equations of second degree can be quite a mouthful. If you have a system of linear equations, you can use `math/matrix`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but what was the exact query you gave to wolfram alpha to get that result?

Comment: @krc solve (x-x1)^2+(y-y1)^2=r^2 and (x-x2)^2+(y-y2)^2=r^2 for x and y

Comment: You're always helping me :)